# Travis Error doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS

Tags: python, django, travis-ci

I am trying to build my app in Travis but I keep getting the following error which I am unable to debug. Can anybody see anything obvious that I may be doing wrong?

[image: Travis Error Log]

RuntimeError:

> Model class
>   Code-Institute-Milestone-Project-05.babysitters.models.Babysitter
>   doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in
>   INSTALLED_APPS.

```html
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'about',
    'accounts',
    'blog',
    'bookings',
    'babysitters',
    'contact',
    'checkout',
    'storages',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_forms_bootstrap',
    'django_gravatar',
    'home',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this. It turns out that my tests.py file was not correctly formatted and was producing this error. Once I rectified this the build passed. Thank you.